# Expression Engine Template Re-use

Tags: expressionengine

I am building a site with EE and was wondering what peoples thoughts are on the situation I have.

Basically I have 3 different channels with similar data that when viewed need to be shown on the same template. So I have a channel for news, artists, and products. When I click on an item in any one of those channels I need to show that data in the same template regardless.

There are 2 ways I can think of to do this but was wondering if anyone had a more elegant solution.

1. Check the URL and open my entries tag with the appropriate channel and then only use the correct custom fields for that channel in the template. (But this would mean I would need to duplicate the code per channel).
2. Open my entries tag with all channels supplied and then put all 3 custom fields at the point in which I need them in the template.

Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you mean by "same template" and "similar data"? Do these channels share a field group, or do they actually contain different fields? Is it the display of the individual entries which is similar, or just the surrounding layout of the page? Products, News, and Events sound to me like they'd have very different types of content, and hence fields.

Some examples of your current code would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you would either [embed templates](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/embedding.html) or use [snippets](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/globals/snippets.html) to overcome this.

For my solutions I have a template group named **global_embeds** which serves as a container for template views I'd like to reuse. This could be the head part and footer part of my general page layout.

Then a snippet for some of the more trivial stuff (like item displaying).

Comment: Thanks Repox, thats the route i'm going down too

Answer (score 1):

You can pass variables into your embeds with [embed variables](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/embedding.html#embed-variables-for-the-embedded-template).

One other thing to note, use Switchee and/or IfElse from Mark Croxton when determining what content to load. Advanced conditionals are terrible for performance.

Comment: Nice, I didnt know about Switchee. It looks like a nice solution to other EE issues too.

Answer (score 0):

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news|artists|products"}

   ...shared content...

   {if channel_short_name == "news"}
       {my_custom_field_for_news}
   {if:elseif channel_short_name == "artists"}
       {my_custom_field_for_artists}
   {if:elseif channel_short_name == "products"}
       {my_custom_field_for_products}
   {/if}

   ...shared content...

{/exp:channel:entries}
```